# Missing vertical line in latex table

Tags: tables, line, vertical, missing

I am using the below code for making a latex table. Unfortunately, when I compile the vertical line of last column is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b!]
\centering
%\footnotesize
\caption{\label{tab:experiments_summary_1}
Summary of fiber experiments. }
\begin{tabular} {|c||c|c|c|*{1}{r@{\,}c@{\,}l|}}
\hline
Type & A
        & B
            & C
                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{D} \\

\hline \hline
1 & 100 & 284198  & 1940876 & $7.6 \times 10^{-6}$ \\
\hline
2 & 100 & 265212  & 1882294 & $1.8 \times 10^{-6}$ \\
\hline
3 & 200 & 200194  & 1472625 & $7.1 \times 10^{-4}$ \\
\hline
4 & 200 & 40477  & 504115 & $4.6 \times 10^{-4}$ \\
\hline
5 & 300 & 36846  & 314694 & $7.2 \times 10^{-3}$ \\
\hline
6 & 315 & 359881  & 3852568 & $1.5 \times 10^{-3}$ \\
\hline
7 & 420 & 123026  & 1039820 & $5.8 \times 10^{-3}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have not shown your source but presumably you omited the final `|`

Comment: I have updated the question with code.

Comment: @Subhani It shows the last vertical line when I compiled it.

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raFnK.png) but note that the table is too wide `Overfull \hbox (63.88pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--34` you are perhaps just clipping the right edge of the table where it overflows the page. add `\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}` after `\footnotesize` to squeeze it a bit

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your suggestion. When I compile only table in separate document, I don not see any issue. However, the problem appears when I do it in my article. I have tried your suggestion but it did not work :(

Comment: that is why we always ask people to post a complete small document that is _an example of the problem_. Start from a copy of your full document, delete everything except the table, check the problem ocurs, then delete everything from the preamble that you can delete while still showing the error. Add the complete resulting document to your question.

Comment: @David Carlislie: I have edited the question, I have deleted everything and its just the table in the document and the last vertical line is still missing.

Comment: @Subhani: What's the purpose of `*{1}{r@{\,}c@{\,}`?  wouldn't a simple `c` type column result in the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your D column is really implemented as three columns `r@{\,}c@{\,}l` (it isn't clear why?)

You only put your math data in the first of these columns so there is no | the final two columns are not used so the final | is never reached.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b!]
\centering
%\footnotesize
\caption{\label{tab:experiments_summary_1}
Summary of fiber experiments. }
\begin{tabular} {|c||c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Type & A
        & B
            & C
                & D \\

\hline \hline
1 & 100 & 284198  & 1940876 & $7.6 \times 10^{-6}$ \\
\hline
2 & 100 & 265212  & 1882294 & $1.8 \times 10^{-6}$ \\
\hline
3 & 200 & 200194  & 1472625 & $7.1 \times 10^{-4}$ \\
\hline
4 & 200 & 40477  & 504115 & $4.6 \times 10^{-4}$ \\
\hline
5 & 300 & 36846  & 314694 & $7.2 \times 10^{-3}$ \\
\hline
6 & 315 & 359881  & 3852568 & $1.5 \times 10^{-3}$ \\
\hline
7 & 420 & 123026  & 1039820 & $5.8 \times 10^{-3}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to align the contents of the last column with respect to "X" sign.

Comment: @Subhani so I guessed but then you would need input something like `5.8 & 10^{-3}`  and a two column preamble entry `r@{$\times$}l|`  and use a `\multicolumn{2}` span for the D heading, that is, the number of cells in the body has to match the preamble

Comment: Thanks, I did something more out of curiosity. I have tried to write the contents in columns B and C as  multiples of 10^4 and 10^5. I used the same approach like you mentioned in the previous comment: \begin{tabular} {|c||c|*{3}{r@{$\times$}l|}}, and \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B}, \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C}. After compiling the elements in these columns are aligned to the left instead of being at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly off-topic suggestions (since your problem is solved by @DavidCarlise answer, +1):

I would use `S` column type in all column except the first, omit vertical lines and for table use (relative new)  `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2} {2} { \l_tblr_childs_total_tl }
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[bt]
    \centering
    \caption{Summary of fiber experiments. }
    \label{tab:experiments_summary_1}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}=1pt, hline{2}=0.6pt, 
             colspec={c Q[c, si={table-format=3}] 
                        Q[c, si={table-format=6.0}]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=7.0}]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=1.1e2}]},
             row{2-Z}     = {rowsep=0pt},
             row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=5pt},
            } 
Type & {{{A}}}
        & {{{B}}}
            & {{{C}}}
                & {{{D}}} \\
% table body
1   & 100   & 284198    & 1940876   & 7.6e-6    \\
2   & 100   & 265212    & 1882294   & 1.8e-6    \\
3   & 200   & 200194    & 1472625   & 7.1e-4    \\
4   & 200   &  40477    &  504115   & 4.6e-4    \\
5   & 300   &  36846    &  314694   & 7.2e-3    \\
6   & 315   & 359881    & 3852568   & 1.5e-3    \\
7   & 420   & 123026    & 1039820   & 5.8e-3    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Similar result can be get by use rules form `booktabs` package and use of standard `tabular` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[bt]
    \centering
    \caption{Summary of fiber experiments. }
    \label{tab:experiments_summary_1}
\begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=3]
                  S[table-format=6.0]
                  S[table-format=7.0]
                  S[table-format=1.1e2]
                }
    \toprule
Type & {A}
        & {B}
            & {C}
                & {D} \\
    \midrule
% table body
1   & 100   & 284198    & 1940876   & 7.6e-6    \\
2   & 100   & 265212    & 1882294   & 1.8e-6    \\
    \addlinespace
3   & 200   & 200194    & 1472625   & 7.1e-4    \\
4   & 200   &  40477    &  504115   & 4.6e-4    \\
    \addlinespace
5   & 300   &  36846    &  314694   & 7.2e-3    \\
6   & 315   & 359881    & 3852568   & 1.5e-3    \\
    \addlinespace
7   & 420   & 123026    & 1039820   & 5.8e-3    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result of both example are almost the same:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you :)

Comment: @Subhani, if answer is "great",  than you can consider to upvote it :-)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to vote it. I will definitely do it in near future :)